# Where can I find good dictionaries for dictionary attacks?

Tags: authentication, passwords, attacks, brute-force, dictionary

I’m wondering where I can find good collections of dictionaries which can be used for dictionary attacks?

I've found some through Google, but I’m interested in hearing about where you get your dictionaries from.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Nice list collected by Ron Bowes you can find here:
https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/index.php/Passwords

Other list is from InsidePro:
https://web.archive.org/web/20120207113205/http://www.insidepro.com/eng/download.shtml.

Answer (score 45):

An important one that hasn't been added to the list is the [crackstation wordlist](http://crackstation.net/buy-crackstation-wordlist-password-cracking-dictionary.htm)

> The list contains every wordlist, dictionary, and password database
>   leak that I could find on the internet (and I spent a LOT of time
>   looking). It also contains every word in the Wikipedia databases
>   (pages-articles, retrieved 2010, all languages) as well as lots of
>   books from Project Gutenberg. It also includes the passwords from some
>   low-profile database breaches that were being sold in the underground
>   years ago.

Best thing is, its free, although you can (and should!) make a donation!

Answer (score 29):

Some additional ones to add to those already suggested

- ftp://ftp.ox.ac.uk/pub/wordlists/ - Lists by language, may be an important point depending on the locations of the users...
- http://www.openwall.com/passwords/wordlists/ - The openwall project lists.
- While not strictly a dictionary site (although it does have some) http://sites.google.com/site/reusablesec/Home/presentations-and-papers has some good presentations on improving the performance of password crackers in general and john the ripper in particular

Comment: Either the Oxford one is now broken or not publicly available.

Answer (score 16):

Try the CrackLib dictionaries: https://web.archive.org/web/20161225012801/http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/cracklib-dicts.html

Answer (score 13):

I tested [the likelihood of collisions of different hashing functions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/what-hashing-algorithm-is-good-for-uniqueness-and-speed). To help test, I tried hashing

- [all 216,553 words in the English language](https://web.archive.org/web/20120420175529/http://www.sitopreferito.it/html/all_english_words.html). Start with those 17.7 bits.
- then the list of all **2,165,530** English words with one *digit* after it. (21.0 bits)
- then the list of all `21,655,300` English words with two *digits* after it. (24.4 bits)
- then the list of all `524,058,260` English words with a possible capital as the first letter, and followed by zero, one, or two digits. (29.0 bits).

With one list of English words you'll cover nearly everyone's password.

**Note:** [XKCD is always relevant](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: When cracking, these permutations (adding a digit, capitalizing) are usually done with "rules". For example, Hashcat takes a given dictionary and applies a user-defined set of rules (http://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=rule_based_attack).  This allows a trade-off between disk space and processor resources.

Comment: Your second link (all words in the English language) gives a 404 now, but it has been [archived by the WayBack machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120420175529/http://www.sitopreferito.it/html/all_english_words.html).

Comment: A list of all english words is an acceptable starting point, but not a particularly good one. For example, the very simple and very popular passwords of "123456", "asdasd" and "letmein" would not be found by an approach used in this post; you want to start with specific lists of common passwords instead of an english dictionary.

Answer (score 9):

Another good source is here http://blog.g0tmi1k.com/2011/06/dictionaries-wordlists/

snippet:

> [Analysis] Dictionaries & Wordlists
>   In general, it's said that using a GOOD 'dictionary' or 'wordlist' (as far as I know, they're the same!) is 'key'. But what makes them GOOD? Most people will say 'the bigger, the better'; however, this isn't always the case... (for the record this isn't my opinion on the matter - more on this later).

Answer (score 7):

You'll find lots of words in lots of languages on the download page for the English Wiktionary. [enwiktionary-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz](http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/enwiktionary-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz) contains just page titles, including phrases - it might have underscores instead of spaces though. (we have English definitions of words from many languages).

And of course there's also WordNet.

(sorry but as a newbie I can only include one link)

Answer (score 7):

All the posts so far have great information, but remember you can always generate word lists yourself with a utility like crunch.

If you have an idea of what the password parameters are (for example, has to be 8-10 chars with only letters and numbers, no symbols), you can pipe crunch to most bruteforce programs with the tailored parameters.

Answer (score 5):

This is one that I have found useful over the years:

https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists

It includes popular passwords, fuzzing based on attack type and popular user names.