# Non English password dictionaries

Tags: passwords, penetration-test, brute-force

What is a good resource for wordlists used in auditing passwords in non english languages. I have extensive wordlists in English ranging to several GB's, but can't find similar resources for other languages.

Comment: I would especially like to know about any password database leaks from non-English sites, for training password entropy algos.

Comment: I would like to know how you deal with different encodings?  This is really important when dealing with non-English dictionaries.  Is there a magical incantation I can use with recode or iconv to convert all of them safely to UTF-8 or something common?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell Wouldn't a really great English password dictionary/ rainbow table eventually cover other languages?

Comment: @ekaj Would it still be an English dictionary in that case?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell I guess, technically, if you have a good enough rainbow table (It would be freaking huge), it is every language.

Answer (score 1):

If you see this question here: [Where can I find good dictionaries for dictionary attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1376/294) you will find many good sites for downloadable dictionaries. However for language specific dictionaries I would recommend:

- Create your own based on Wikipedia. My PowerShell script does that: https://github.com/ChrisAD/wiki-dictionary-creator
- Go look for Scrabble wordlists for the target language. E.g. Google `scrabble wordlist github french`