# Password recovery tool over telnet or http basic auth

Tags: passwords

In my feeble attempt to secure my router, I disabled the service login and either

1. changed the "admin" login and the password, or
2. changed only the password for the "admin" login

Normally, I would hard-reset the router, but this one is special and on loan with various settings for a limited trial (contains SIP settings, tweaked timeouts etc).  The tech guy from ISP told me it'll cost a callout to reconfigure the trial router all over again, so I'm stuck with password *recovery*.

If I browse to the gateway address, it comes up with an auth request, not a webpage, but a "this server requires a username and password" type.
I can telnet to the gateway, which ends up with 3 tries at login.

Computers on this network: OSX Lion and Windows (XP/8).

What tools can I use?  I looked around and I could be wrong but JTR looked like it attacks a hash file rather than cracking over telnet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff stated, THC-Hydra is a good application of choice. I'll try to cover the basic usage for your situation.

[You will need a dictionary file](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/where-can-i-find-good-dictionaries-for-dictionary-attacks) unless you want to bruteforce every single character possible.

In the examples change the following fields:

- dictionary file: Your password file
- ip address: The router
- protocol: Either telnet or http-head. Incase of https just type https-head and add -S
- username file: A file with a list of usernames to bruteforce

**Known username with dictionary attack:**

```
hydra -l admin -P <dictionary file> -e nsr -f <ip address> <protocol>
```

**Known username with bruteforce attack.**

Generate 3-8 char long password with both cases and numbers:

```
hydra -l admin -x 3:8:aA1 -e nsr -f <ip address> <protocol>
```

**Unknown username**

```
hydra -L <username file> -P <dictionary file> -e nsr -f <ip address> <protocol>
```

Ofcourse reading the manual will tell you this aswell.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [Hydra](http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/). It provides for trying passwords over a network.